# How Update Apt-cache Repository?

Tags: google-chrome, repository, updates

i have a local repository for Ubuntu machines.

it work with `Apt-Cacher-Ng`.

when i create repository, google-chrome-stable version was 59.

now i want to update google chrome version 72 but when run this:

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install google-chrome-stable
```

result is :

google-chrome-stable is already the newest version.

how i can update apt-cache repository that don't install old packages?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling the deb file from Google? If not, download the latest `.deb` file from Google and install it from there.